# Run code that decides if checkbox/radio will be checked before actually checking anything (javascript)

Tags: javascript, checkbox, radio-button, preventdefault

I'm building a cart app in Javascript and jQuery that needs to run some logic whenever a product is clicked. The clicked elements are radio buttons and checkboxes and the code will check if the right conditions are met for adding the product to the cart.

My initial way of trying to do this was to run `preventDefault()` at the start of my function, run some logic that decides if it's ok to add the item, and if so, add it to the cart and check the input element.

Looks sort of like this:

```
$(document).on("click","[data-item]", function(event) {
    cart.updateCart(this, event);
});

cart.updateCart = function(target, event) {
    if (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    // pseudo code...
    if (conditionIsMet === true) {
        cart.addItem(target);
    }
}

cart.addItem = function(item) {           
    products.push(item);
    var element = $('[value=' + item.key + ']');
    element.prop('checked', true);
};
```

My problem is that it seems that I can't use `element.prop('checked', true);` in my addItem function, since preventDefault stops that.

Can I get around this someway or what route should I go to get my wanted functionality? I really wan't to stop the form elements from getting checked at all and only check or uncheck through my app instead.

Comment: I think your `element` is not referring to right element.

Comment: Yashika Garg, it is the right element. The element in the DOM that needs to be checked is the element with the value that is equal to item.key. If I do console.log(element); the correct element is outputted. And whats more, I can do the prop.checked part in the console on that element, so that works. That is what makes me think that it's the preventDefault() part that stops it in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it's not possible to set the `checked` property of a checkbox right after `preventDefault` was called on it. Try wrapping your `prop` call with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), which will make sure that the update of the `checked` property occurs in another turn of the event loop:

```js
$("#cb").on("click", function(event) {
  updateCart(this, event);
});

const updateCart = function(target, event) {
  if (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  // pseudo code...
  if (true === true) {
    addItem(target);
  }
}

const addItem = function(item) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#cb').prop('checked', true);
  })
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb">
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain this code? How does this work? What does the arrow do?

Comment: Sorry, the arrow is just a shorthand way to write a function in ES6. I changed my code. I'll also try to add a little explanation to my answer!

Comment: Ah. I'm not that familiar with ES6 yet, and also would not like to think about compatibility issues that might arise from using that. Add that explanation if you like :)

Comment: Done! 
If you don't have to support IE, compatibility is pretty good these days - give it a shot when you find the time, i couldn't live without it anymore ;)

Comment: Thanks! Yes I just haven't gotten to that point yet, still learning a lot of basics, but I will check on it soon. Your solution seems to work as it should in my code, so thanks a lot!